# Using Flow Designer, I'm trying to iterate through a list of items and put the value of a field in a list separated by a semi-colon

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I'm iterating through a collection of child object records and grabbing the values of 3 different fields and I'm adding them to one field on the Master (Asset Roll-up).  As I assign the child object's values, I add a semi-colon as a separator.  I assign them to a variable in the Flow, then assign them to the SObject variable and Update it to the actual field in Salesforce.  When I do, I get an extra semi-colon for each blank value, because each field needs a semi-colon after each value.

Parent Object = Parent Object, Field = Asset Rollup.
Child Object = Child Object, Fields = Asset Name, Other Asset Name, Archived Asset Name.

Record 1:  Asset Name = "Carrots".  Asset Other Name = blank.  Archived Asset Name = blank.

Record 2:  Asset Name = "Peas".  Asset Other Name = blank.  Archived Asset Name = blank.

Record 3:  Asset Name = "Potatoes"  Asset Other Name = "Spuds", Archived Asset Name = blank.
Asset Roll-up:  "Carrots;;Peas;;Potatoes;Spuds;"

If I remove the semi-colon, the values have no separator.  I've even created 3 new fields, one for each field from the Child object and used a workflow rule to populate the values and am still getting the extra semi-colons.

I can provide screen shots.

Comment: You may need to add an extra conditional to make sure the value isnt null. If null, add empty string, if not add the semi-colon.

Comment: So I have a decision tree that says "if the value is populated, then populate this variable with the value + a semi-colon", and "if the value is a blank string, then proceed to the next decision (does the Asset Other Name' have a value), etc.  But you're suggesting adding another assignment to add a blank value?